# Hide or disable UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm looking to hide or disable `UIButton`. I'm using `IBAction` : here is the code in

.h file

```
-(IBAction)siteButton:(id)sender;
```

.m file

```
-(IBAction)siteButton:(id)sender
{


    JSONData = [jsonLoader getJSONData];


    NSString *mySiteString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[JSONData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"mySiteButton"]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mySiteString]];

    NSLog(@"%@",mySiteString);

}
```

Comment: @Prince I will add in app purchase to unhide this button

Comment: whats the problem here???

Comment: not getting your issue

Comment: @Prince I need to hide this button if the user dose not buy the app, in the free version this button will be hidden.

Comment: @Sport I need to hide this button if the user dose not buy the app, in the free version this button will be hidden. –

Comment: yourbutton.hidden=yes ; i am not sure in this case it will work

Comment: @YousefAbuSallamah You should have once google it before posting it to stack overflow. There are plenty of resourses from where you could get the answer of this or you can refer to previously answered questions in stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a reference to your button, via an IBOutlet. You can create one by ctrl+click dragging from the button into the header (.h) of your class. Similar to how you would create the IBAction. Then you can set the button hidden depending on your condition:

```
[self.siteButton setHidden:condition];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create IBOutlet for your button and then in .m file add the below code.

```
button.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: do I have to put the connection in the IBAction or IBOutlet ?

Comment: In button.hidden = YES; button is the IBOutlet for UIButton